# How to copy/paste values in a to a set dimensional array and delete after done

Tags: excel, vba

I am having issues formulating a vba code.

My entire goal is the following:

- I want to add a Row to a named table (in this case it is named `July2020table`).
- Paste values into this row from range `A20:E20`
- Delete values from `A20:E20` after it has been pasted into `newrow`.

This is what I currently have.

```
Sub AddRowtToBudgetTable()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("July2020Table")
Dim newrow As ListRow
Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add
Range("A20:E20").Copy
```

This code is currently able to add a row to the table, however I am unable to paste values from `A20:E20` into this table.

Comment: You could turn on the macro recorder, do what you want to do, stop the macro recorder and look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by #teylyn ;-)

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddRowtToBudgetTable()    
Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("July2020Table")
    Dim newrow As ListRow
    Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add
    Range("A20:E20").Copy Destination:=newrow.Range
    Range("A20:E20").ClearContents    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this if it works? Just modify your last row of code

```
Range("A20:E20").Copy newrow.Range
Range("A20:E20").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft 'or Shift:=xlToUp depending on you
```